# How to set a slotted input field's form attribute to a form inside shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, forms, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a custom element like this:

```
<my-magic-form>
    #shadowRoot:
    <form id="some_id_name_invisible_to_end_users">
      <input disabled name="entry_id"></input>
      <slot name="fields_toFill"></slot>
    </form>
</my-magic-form>
```

The users of my widget are supposed to add their own input fields like this:

```
<my-magic-form>
  <input slot="fields_toFill" value="some_value1"/>
  <textarea slot="fields_toFill"/>
</my-magic-form>
```

My question is: how can I link those two slotted `<input>` and `<textarea>` controls to the `<form>` element inside the shadow DOM of my widget? The end users are not required to know the inner form's id of my widget, so they cannot set the `form` attribute when they author; and I've tried programmatically setting this attribute only to find out that this attribute is read-only!

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to move the light DOM into the Shadow DOM content. 
Listen to the `slotchange` event then move the `assignedNodes()` before the `<slot>` element.

```
var form = this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'form' )
var slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'slot' )

slot.addEventListener( 'slotchange', () => {
    for (var field of slot.assignedNodes()) {
        form.insertBefore( field, slot ) 
    } 
} )
```

Alternately, if you don't want to move the light DOM fields, you should duplicate them as `<input type="hidden">` fields, for exemple whan the `<form>` is submitted.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any potential drawback to such a brute force way of defeating the boundary of shadow and light? I wish there were a more elegant way?

Comment: Depends on the use case. The more elegant way is the alternate one